# conditional backspace. I want to use conditional backspace inside printf

Tags: c

In a program I want to erase a word if a condition gets true.
is there any way to do this.
I am thinking of using escape sequence.

```
/* program to print number into words.  */ 

# include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char *single_numbers[10]={" ","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"};
    char *tens_numbers[9]={"Twenty","Thirty","Fourty","Fifty","Sixty","Seventy","Eighty","Ninety"};
    char *teens[9]={"Eleven","Twelve","Thirteen","Fourteen","Fifteen","Sixteen","Seventeen","Eighteen","Nineteen"};
    int number,thousands,hundreds,tens,units,temp;
    printf("enter the number");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    if(number>9999)
    {
        printf("please enter a number between 0-9999");
    }else
    {
        thousands=number/1000;
        hundreds=(number%1000)/100;
        temp=(number%100);
        tens=temp/10;
        units=number%10;
        if(temp>=20)
            printf("%s thousand %s hundred %s %s only",
                    single_numbers[thousands],
                    single_numbers[hundreds],
                    tens_numbers[tens-2],
                    single_numbers[units]);
        else
            printf("%s thousand %s hundred %s only ",
                    single_numbers[thousands],
                    single_numbers[hundreds],
                    teens[temp-11]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you've already written?  What language?  Show us the program with all of the other pieces in place, and a comment for "here's where I want to erase the word XYZ".

Comment: is this allowed? char backspace= "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";

Comment: Yes, this is allowed, you're just being asked to provide more details to your question so we have an actual starting point for writing answers.  You can edit your question to include the details -- add enough detail and the moderators will reopen the question.

Comment: Better construct a whole line (e.g. with `snprintf`....) then `fputs` it...

Comment: In the above program when I give input as 2014 I am getting the result as two thousand hundred fourteen only . so  I want to use a conditional backspace in end printf statements so that hundred gets erased. when hundreds place is zero.

Comment: I've voted to have your question re-opened now that it's clear what you want to do.  After it's taken off hold, people can write answers to it.

Comment: Until then, I'll say that it's easier to modify your program to not print that part in the first place.  Maybe break your `printf()` call into multiple pieces wrapped in `if` statements -- print the thousands, then the hundreds, then the rest.

Comment: for example 
int main()
{
int n=1;
char backspace[8]= "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";
char space[10]="   ";
printf("mummy %s daddy", n==1? backspace: space);
return (0);
} Here the escape sequence is stored as a character.but I want to use it as a backspace. is there any way to do this.

Comment: So switch your idea around.  Instead of conditionally backspacing to erase "mummy", conditionally print "mummy":  `int main() { int n=1; printf("%sdaddy", n==1 ? "" : "mummy "); return (0); }`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use a backspace (`'\b'`) to overwrite something already printed to the screen, but it isn't a technique you'd typically use.

Instead of using a backspace character to overwrite something you've already printed, modify your code to only print the parts that you want.  Here's a good starting point, but you'll need to modify it to cover situations like 1000, 0, and 1001.

```
    if (thousands > 0)
        printf("%s thousand ", single_numbers[thousands]);
    if (hundreds > 0)
        printf("%s hundred ", single_numbers[hundred]);
    if (temp >= 20)
        printf("%s %s only\n", tens_numbers[tens-2], single_numbers[units]);
    else
        printf("%s only\n", teens[temp-11]);
```

The other way to accomplish your goal would be to use `sprintf()` to print into a buffer, and selectively truncate the buffer to remove written characters.  But consider how inefficient that is -- why print and then erase when you can just skip the printing step entirely?